# unexpected implicit "DEFAULT NULL" on non-null columns when `INSERT IGNORE` is used

Tags: mysql

I just ran this on MySql 8 using InnoDB

```
CREATE TABLE TuneName
(
        id          BIGINT        NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        tune_id     BIGINT        NOT NULL,
        name        VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
        norm        VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
        base_weight FLOAT         NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
        weight      FLOAT         NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
        UNIQUE (tune_id, name),
        FOREIGN KEY (tune_id) REFERENCES Tune (id)
                ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I am surprised to discover that `name` and `norm` are implicitly `DEFAULT NULL`, as shown by `show columns from TuneName`:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tune_id     | bigint       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| norm        | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| base_weight | float        | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| weight      | float        | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

although they are quite explicitly `NOT NULL` in the schema

When I `INSERT` I get an expected error

```
mysql> INSERT INTO TuneName ( tune_id, name, weight, base_weight ) VALUES (99, 'foo',1.0, 1.0);
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'norm' doesn't have a default value
```

however with `INSERT IGNORE`

```
mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO TuneName ( tune_id, name, weight, base_weight ) VALUES (99, 'foo',1.0, 1.0);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from TuneName;
+----+---------+------+------+-------------+--------+
| id | tune_id | name | norm | base_weight | weight |
+----+---------+------+------+-------------+--------+
|  1 |      99 | foo  |      |           1 |      1 |
+----+---------+------+------+-------------+--------+
```

I want `INSERT IGNORE` to not-insert if the `UNIQUE(tune_id,name)` constraint fails, which is why that exists, I do not want it to succeed if `norm` is missing.

Can I enforce that in the schema?

Comment: It's not setting it to `NULL`, it's setting it to an empty string.

Comment: You could use a `CHECK` constraint to prevent an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html says:

> Data conversions that would trigger errors abort the statement if IGNORE is not specified. With IGNORE, invalid values are adjusted to the closest values and inserted; warnings are produced but the statement does not abort.

You can't use this feature to do what you describe. You'll have to use a CHECK constraint or a trigger with SIGNAL to abort the INSERT.